# How to use two different .eslintrc.json in VS Code?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, eslint, eslintrc

How can I use one eslint ruleset for Node.js side Javascript and another ruleset for clientside Javascript in VS Code?

Comment: Do you have two distinct folders for each side?

Comment: Yes. server.js is in project's root folder, client js is in js subfolder.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but how about having an `.eslintrc` in root folder for your back-end and an `.eslintrc` in `client/`? However, you might need to check that there is no conflict between `./.eslintrc` and `./client/.eslintrc`. If there is a conflict, `./client/.eslintrc` must override rule

Comment: OK, this seems to work. Thank you!

Comment: Nice! if you don't mind, I posted a more formal answer with quoted ESLint documentation. Please accept it if that works for you or post your self-answer to mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- use `./.eslintrc` at root folder for your back-end
- use `./client/.eslintrc`. Add `root: true` in your `./client/.eslintrc` if you want to fully dissociate client linting from back-end linting.

[ESLint configuration files follow "first found" rules](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#using-configuration-files-1)

> ESLint will automatically look for them in the directory of the file to be linted, and in successive parent directories all the way up to the root directory of the filesystem (unless root: true is specified)